# Enable logging using log4net!

Tags: c#, log4net, error-logging

Is it possible to log to a database and a log file from the same program using log4net?

I want certain sections of my code to log to a DB instead of a log file. Everything else can continue to log as before.

Comment: http://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/config-examples.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the log4net configuration you just need to add another appender and its done. Have a look [here](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/config-examples.html) on how to configure appenders.

Lets have a config example ( stolen from the [docs](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/manual/configuration.html) )

```
    <log4net>
        <!-- A1 is set to be a ConsoleAppender -->
        <appender name="A1" type="log4net.Appender.ConsoleAppender">

            <!-- A1 uses PatternLayout -->
            <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
                <conversionPattern value="%-4timestamp [%thread] %-5level %logger %ndc - %message%newline" />
            </layout>
        </appender>


        <root>
            <level value="DEBUG" />
            <appender-ref ref="A1" />
<!-- as many appenders as you want -->
            <appender-ref ref="...." />
            <appender-ref ref="...." />
        </root>
    </log4net>
```

Answer (score 1):

As Felice said, just add another appender in your configuration file, here's an example of a config-file with multiple appenders:

http://pastebin.ca/2048432